# Text Indent - IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I've been following a few posts already on this topic. It seems that the fix is to add

```
text-indent:-9999px; 
text-transform:capitalize; 
font-size:0; 
display:block; 
line-height:0;
```

However on my site I want to display some icons in an inline-block. Switching the CSS to that then makes the icons dissapear again.

Has anyone managed to achieve this? If so how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display them inline, i would suggest the following:

```
text-indent:-9999px; 
display:block;
float:left;
```

I've coded up an example for you here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fTDe7/

Comment: Ah ha! A Simple float to do it. Thanks a lot